# How can I make `read` read from stdin?

Tags: bash, read

bash builtin command `read`  is said to accept input from stdin, but why does the following not read in anything?

```
$ printf "%s" "a   b" | read line
$ printf "%s" "$line"
$
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not with `read` itself, but with the pipe. In bash, that causes the second command (`read`, in this case) to run in a subshell. So it will actually `read` into a `line` variable, only that variable exists in a subshell and will vanish as soon as the pipeline completes.

(Note that other shells behave differently, most notably ksh will run the last command of a pipeline in the current shell, so this snippet might work in ksh. In bash it will not work, as you're seeing.)

A possible solution is to use `<(...)` process substitution for the first part of the pipeline, with an additional `<` to redirect that to stdin:

```
read line < <(printf "%s" "a   b")
```

In this particular case, you could do without the `printf` command, then `<<<` would also work:

```
read line <<<"a   b"
```